# Connect app to real MYSQL database

Tags: ios, mysql, react-native

I've used React Native for about 2 months now and I've learned a lot already. Now I wanna know how to connect my app to a SQL database. I want to be able to log in, register and chat. I've already built the log in, register and chat screen but I just need one function that can communicate online with a database, I guess. This must be possible... If so, how? A quick answer would be highly appreciated!

Update: This question was asked simply because I didn't recognize some programming terms back then... If you are asking yourself the same thing, search for "RESTful API" and then your desired programming language.

**Update**

This question was initially asked bescause of my lack of knowledge with backend and general APIs (Look at the title, it's obvious). After one year plus (now), I'm selling my own services and products to other corporations, professionally.

Comment: exactly how are you logging in, if there's no back-end system to validate/authenticate the login?

Comment: That's the thing, Isn't there any pre-made back-end system for React Native? I was watching this dudes tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpiF5IhavaY) or way but I didn't understand how'd I could connect the back-end to my own server.

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting is a web api. Essentially, you will build a web application that you can access over http. You will most likely want to use RESTful web calls. Your web application will then take those REST requests, access your database, operate on your data and return a data response (JSON or XML). Then your iOS app would receive that JSON response and do whatever it needs to with it.

You can build a REST API out of pretty much any server side language, so pick one you like or feel comfortable with and start there.

Comment: Wow thanks for this answer! I understand, really! But what "Server side language" should I use? PHP, Ruby? Just want to make it as simple and as comprehensible as possible! (For now atleast)

Comment: @BluDay It's totally up to you! If you want to go for PHP, you can go for Wordpress to build an API really quick. Or Codeigniter for that matter. Web API 2.0 for C#.NET. Or you can create express server on top of node. There are tons of options available.

Comment: Another popular one is Java with Spring MVC.

Comment: Thanks you guys, this was really helpful! Also I tried it and it worked!